# Benchmarking MySQL on win7

Tags: mysql, php, nginx, performance, benchmark

I've setup a nginx server running php 5.3.6 and mysql 5.5.1.3.

My computer is an AMD quadcore 9650, 4gb ram, 500gb 7200rpm HD.

I ran the [PHP MySQL Benchmark Tool v. 0.1](http://unbeknownst.net/?p=321), and got the following results:

```
Testing a(n) MYISAM table using 100000 rows.    
Successfully created database speedtestdb
Sucessfully created table speedtesttable
Table Type Verified: MYISAM ..     
Done. 100000 inserts in 19.73628 seconds or 5067 inserts per second. 
Done. 100000 row reads in 0.2801 seconds or 357015 row reads per second.    
Done. 100000 updates in 4.03876 seconds or 24760 updates per second.
```

I'm wondering where this stands as far as performance goes, and what are some steps I can take if any to improve on this. I'm not trying to make anything fantastic, just getting a feel for how to best optimize a web server in this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The performance you're seeing on that hardware is pretty close to optimal for a 'generic' install. MySQL installations are typically tuned toward a particular work type (heavy write, heavy read, or 'balance'). If you want to get more in depth details (To find out if it's MySQL underpinnings or hardware related) launch perfmon for Windows. Chances are your biggest bottleneck is the drive. But like I said, for what you've got it's pretty much what one should expect.